# Unmarshalling using JAXB for collections

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<layout>
    <panel>
    <ComboBox incEmpty="true">
            <label>Shipment Types:</label>
            <fieldName>StringData1</fieldName>   
            <type>static</type> 
            <element>Samples</element>
            <element>Gifts</element>
            <element>Possessions</element>
            <element>Merchandise</element>
    </ComboBox>
    <CheckBox>
        <label>Report Usage:</label>
        <fieldName>IntData1</fieldName>
    </CheckBox>
</panel>
</layout>
```

Basically I need to create a Swing panel from the XML. There will be several occurrences of `<ComboBox>` and `<CheckBox>`. I need to retrieve them in the order in which they have been added in the XML, to allow me to render them on screen in the correct order. 
I need to unmarshall this XML and generate the code. I am unable to come up with an XSD that will generate me the correct classes to get this to work. 
I know I will need a collection to be able to order the items in the correct order. 
Towards that I created an updated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<layout>
    <panel>
        <component>
            <ComboBox incEmpty="true">
                <label>Shipment Types:</label>
                <fieldName>StringData1</fieldName>
                <type>static</type>
                <element>Samples</element>
                <element>Gifts</element>
                <element>Possessions</element>
                <element>Merchandise</element>
            </ComboBox>
        </component>
        <component>
            <CheckBox>
                <label>Report Usage:</label>
                <fieldName>IntData1</fieldName>
            </CheckBox>
        </component>
    </panel>
</layout>
```

The idea was that I could programatically make `Component` as an interface and do something along the lines `ComboBox implements Component` and `CheckBox implements Component` and then in `Panel` something like:

```
public List<Component> getComponent() {
       if (component == null) {
           component = new ArrayList<Component>();
       }
       return this.component;
}
```

I could then check each item in the collection for type (`instanceof`) and process it accordingly. However, JAXB does not seem to cope very well with interfaces. 
I tried to use the scenario described here: [How to wrap sublist with jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911953/how-to-wrap-sublist-with-jaxb), however it does not suit my case as I need to return different objects as part of the same collection.

Any help will be much appreciated. I can post xsds here if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `choice` structure in your XML Schema, this will cause an annotation like the following to be generated.  What it means is that if either the `ComboBox` or `CheckBox` element is encountered then it will put it in the `component` collection.

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="ComboBox", type=ComboBox.class),
    @XmlElement(name="CheckBox", type="CheckBox.class)
})
public List<Component> getComponent() {
       if (component == null) {
           component = new ArrayList<Component>();
       }
       return this.component;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Blaise for pointing me in the right direction.Much appreciated. This is the xsd I ended up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="layout" type="layout" />
    <xsd:complexType name="layout">
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="panel" type="panel" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="panel">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="ComboBox" type="ComboBox" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element name="CheckBox" type="CheckBox" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element name="InputBox" type="InputBox" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>  
    <xsd:complexType name="ComboBox">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="label" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="fieldName" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="element" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="incEmpty" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="CheckBox">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="label" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="fieldName" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="InputBox">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="label" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="fieldName" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Then, in my Panel class I have:

```
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "ComboBox", type = ComboBox.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "CheckBox", type = CheckBox.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "InputBox", type = InputBox.class)
    })
    protected List<MyComponent> component;
...
...
    public List<MyComponent> getComponent() {
        if (component == null) {
           component = new ArrayList<MyComponent>();
         }
        return this.component;
    }
```

This, along with a basic interface `MyComponent` which is then implemented by my relevant classes `CheckBox`, `ComboBox`, `InputBox` allows me to get the result I was after. 
Thanks again, Blaise